# Delete multiple lines with sed

Tags: sed

HI I want to delete lines with this kind of text:

```
lorem
boringfunction("ads");
insum
boringfunction("qwe");
lorem
```

to

```
lorem
insum
lorem
```

Comment: Cool. Do you have a question? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete all lines containing boringfuntion, you can use this:

```
sed '/boringfunction/d' file
```